# If $a$ and $b$ are coprime, prove that $a^2+b^2$ and $a^2b^2$ are coprime

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $a$ and $b$ are coprime, prove that $a^2+b^2$ and $a^2b^2$ are coprime.

Answer:

We have to prove $\gcd(a^2+b^2,a^2b^2)=1$, $\gcd(a,b)=1$. Then $\gcd(a^2,b^2)=1$. Now we have $\gcd(a^2,a^2+b^2)=1$ and $\gcd(b^2,a^2+b^2)=1$ by $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(p\pm q)$.

Then I am lost.

Comment: You're almost there. If you know ${\rm gcd}(r,z)= 1$ and ${\rm gcd}(s,z)= 1$, what can you say about ${\rm gcd}(rs,z)$? Can you find those conditions in what you have already derived?

Comment: No please explain

Comment: If $r$ and $z$ have no common (prime) divisor, and $s$ and $z$ also have no common (prime) divisor, then $rs$ and $z$ can't have one, either. Any common prime divisor $p$ must divide $r$ or $s$ and thus at least one assumption is not fullfilled. So it follows that ${\rm gcd} (rs,z)=1$.

Comment: OK I got what you sat

Comment: If $p|a^2b^2$ then $p|a$ or $p|b$ and not both (since they are coprime). wlog let it be $a$, then $p$ is a factor of $a^2$ and not of $b^2$, so is not a factor of $a^2+b^2$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $p$ be a common prime factor of $a^2 + b^2$ and $a^2 b^2$, and recall that for any integer $n$, $p | n \iff p | n^2$. Thus $p | a^2 b^2$ implies $p | ab$, so $p$ must divide both of $a^2 + b^2 \pm 2ab = (a\pm b)^2$; i.e., both $a+b$ and $a-b$ must be multiples of $p$. Thus, both $a$ and $b$ are multiples of $p/2$. If $p$ is odd, then $a$ and $b$ have $p$ as a common factor, so we're done. If $p = 2$, then $p | a^2 b^2$ forces at least one of $a$ and $b$ to be even; as $a^2 + b^2$ is even, both $a$ and $b$ must be even. QED.

Comment: Mark Bennet's comment on the original question is a somewhat similar but more elegant method.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $(a,b)=1$. [Bezout's Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) says there are $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$ so that
$$
ax+by=1\tag1
$$
Then
$$
1=(ax+by)^3=\underbrace{\left(ax^3+3bx^2y\right)}_ua^2+\underbrace{\left(3axy^2+by^3\right)}_vb^2\tag2
$$
Rearranging $(2)$, we get
$$
u\left(a^2+b^2\right)+(v-u)b^2=1\tag3
$$
and
$$
(u-v)a^2+v\left(a^2+b^2\right)=1\tag4
$$
Multiplying $(3)$ and $(4)$ yields
$$
\left(\left(a^2+b^2\right)uv+\left(a^2u-b^2v\right)(u-v)\right)\left(a^2+b^2\right)-(u-v)^2a^2b^2=1\tag5
$$
Thus, $\left(a^2+b^2,a^2b^2\right)=1$.